# New Resource with default ownership of current user

Tags: symfony, sylius

How can i add some additional checking with the Resource Bundle to allow me to auto assign the new resource to the current User (also check they are logged in) and when editing check that the current user owns the resource?

Is this possible through settings or do i need to override each action in the controller?

Originally posted here - https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/issues/5907

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to summarize:

As I understood you have 2 cases. 
First is to create a owned resource. 
Best approach would be to decorate a default resource factory, where you will inject some UserContext to determine a currently logged in user. Or just pass it to the factory method as a second argument.

Second one is to update a resource. You want to allow editing of resource only to an owner? Some repository method, which would receive not only resource id, but also a current user will do the job. Then, you would have a method findByIdAndCustomer, so only allowed user would be able to access an editing page. Otherwise an error would be displayed. I guess it would be 404.

If this is what you want, you will end up with two overridden resources(custom factory and repository) and you will need to handle rest in yaml when defining a routing. No controller changes needed.

Some comparison of both approaches:

1. Resolving it with listener would be probably faster (only one class needed) and easier.
2. Managing it by event listener would not require any routing changes.
3. Overriding a factory will ensure, that this object will be always created with given user. Event is dispatched after creation, but before persisting it to the database.
4. Custom repository method will ensure, that the editing page cannot be even displayed by not-owner.

Both are correct. IMHO first is faster, second one is cleaner. Just decide what you need

Answer (score 2):

You can use events fired by the controller for that. Have a look here: http://docs.sylius.org/en/latest/bundles/general/events.html

In the listener, you should inject the `security.context` service, which will allow you to check whether the user is logged in or not.

Edit: Please have a look at @Łukasz's answer, which contains alternative, a bit cleaner solution. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Paweł is recommending events, as I also first, but Łukasz was suggesting some overriding of factory and repositories.

Although I agree both of them are correct and help the original poster to achieve his goal, I'm wondering what are the arguments behind both of them.

The solely purpose of this comment is the debate of these two solutions.